# SQL Query doesn't work as expected with pdo + OUTPUT

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm trying to soft lock a record and return it at the same time. This query works as expected in SQL Management Studio or Navicat however when I put it in the code it updates the record but doesn't return anything:

```
$query = $dbh2->query("UPDATE TOP (1) [_partners_customers_details] SET STATUS = '1' 
                      OUTPUT B.ID AS NEWID,inserted.* FROM _partners_customers_details A
                      LEFT JOIN Billing_partners_customers B ON A.CIID = B.ID
                      WHERE A.STATUS IS NULL
                      ");
$OUTPUTS = $query->fetchall();
print_r($OUTPUTS);
```